# meanJS with Java backend

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, tomcat, mean-stack

Me and couple of my friends want to do a web application and eventually we want to write in 3 different OS for phone applications, I am insisting to use meanJS for the front-end but since it is a full stack framework I am not sure if we can use Java for some background features:

1) How efficient and safe it can be? Specifically; if we use meanJS with Java, we will choose to use MongoDB to save some profile information(front-end) and save some information that our Java feature needs - how safe is the connection of the back-end Java feature to MongoDB? Please explain with specifics.

2) Is Node.js a good way to make this web application? or Should we just use angularJS for front-end and Java for backgend with SQL/MongoDB and save all the information(includign profile information) in the backend part and make the communication between angularJS and Java through Tomcat server? Please explain with specifics too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Angular and MongoDB in your application, that is fine, but its not a MEAN stack if you're missing Node+Express.

1) Can't comment on this, never used either.

2) It's hard to say if Node is good for your application without knowing what your application is. It may be the best choice, it may be the worst. In the end, if you're not sure, go with what you're most comfortable with. The stack you explained is definitely possible, and if you feel like you can pull it off, then go for it.

Comment: I just didn't mention Node+Express of course I will use them, that's why I asked my second question :)


2) Front-end will contain profiles and you can think about backend that it will contain different kind of features that should save data in a databse. Would your answer change?

Comment: I brought it up because that is what the EN in MEAN stands for. The MEAN stack can't really be changed and still be called a MEAN stack. The point of the stack is that everything from client side to server side is written in JavaScript. If this doesn't tickle your fancy, and you're not so proficient in Javascript, then the MEAN stack may not be for you, and you should go with Java.

Comment: I am proficient in JS, I want to use it because it saves a lot of time in front-end (I have used it before for another web application). I will use MEAN or not front-end will be written in Javascript (Angular, JQuery, whatever we decide) and back-end features will be written in Java for efficiency for those features. I am just very curious about efficiency and safety in case we use them together.

Comment: Well to my understanding, Node isn't the fastest back-end out there. If you're very concerned about performance, I think Java is definitely a better choice.

Comment: Safety is more important to me, I am thinking that if we use MEAN the connection between MongoDB and Java part won't be too safe. I am not sure though

Comment: Not sure. Like I said, I've never used either, but I have to imagine that the connection is as safe as you make it. So it can be safe or unsafe no matter what language you use